# Cannot read packageName from /***/***/AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I know this question is duplicate and has been asked a lot, I read all the answers from all the questions and none of them worked. I'm trying to build a react native app for release and I get this error

```
➜  android git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew assembleRelease
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig'.
> Cannot read packageName from /run/media/christopher/warzone/projects/mobile/in_development/fundiapp/mobileapp/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I tried every solution from the questions asked and none of them worked. These are my files

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest package="com.mobileapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="********"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

bild.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobileapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('*****.keystore')
            storePassword "*****"
            keyAlias "*****"
            keyPassword "*****"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `applicationId` field in build.gradle, add applicationId inside defaultConfig ("com.mobileapp") - your package name - or whatever package name you want:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mobileapp"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot to return it but it was there, i removed it to test some things and forgot to return it while i was  posting the question,  and it doesn't work even with setting the applicationId

Comment: Hm, ok.. try first clean project and then assemble it again. ./gradlew clean and after that assembleRelease

Comment: Also try to change package name and check if you have manifest file in file path of project -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thank you for your replies. I found out that the manifest was looked at the wrong directory, 'android/src/' instead of 'android/app/src/' so i renamed the app folder to src and then moved the original src content up to new src folder. Now i'm getting erros from .java files that the packages can not be found

Comment: one of the errors 'error: package com.facebook.react does not exist'

Comment: Ok, now you should also take care about your java classes that they are in correct folders.. they should be in your case in folder -> android -> app -> src -> main-> java-> com -> mobileapp -> java files (MainActivity, MainApplication)

Comment: Check for example this react-native project how it's structured:
https://github.com/taskrabbit/ReactNativeSampleApp
This project has package name "com.sample" and take care that you will have same structure.

Comment: if i use that directory structure, i get the original error. To get rid of the error i have to have the directory structure as android->src->main->java->com->mobileapp->java files, and after doing so i get 28 errors saying all the imports in the java files can not be found, it's as if they are looked at the wrong place, i hope there is a reference somewhere i have to change

Comment: Follow the structure as it is defined in project link I send you. Regarding imports, check if you have in your java files package name set correct.
package com.mobileapp; you can find this line of code on top of each java file in your project.